# How to see the logs if we have deployed our Spring Boot Application in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04

We have developed a Spring Boot application and deployed in Google Cloud Platform (GCP). It is Compute Engine and we have `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` as Operating System and `Apache Tomcat 8.5.3` as Web Server.

In this application, we have used System.out.println() statements and sometimes we are throwing the exceptions as well.

> Now I want to see the logs which are generated by either `System.out.println()` or through the `Exceptions` but how to see the console in `Google Cloud Platform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot see the logs in GCP directly via `System.out.println` or `Exceptions`

There are two ways to achieve this:

**Possible but not recommended**: Use filewriter to write logs into a file, access the file and read it

**Recommended**: Add logger into your application.
For this, include apache commons logging into your application's `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Write logs as per requirement:

```
@RestController    
public class ExampleController {
private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(ExampleController.class);

@RequestMapping("/<custom-url>")
public String function() {
    String message = "Example message written to the log";
    String secondMessage = "Second example written to the log";
    LOGGER.info(message);
    LOGGER.info(secondMessage);
    return message;
}
}
```

You can use Logger into as many functions and as many controllers you like, it will be added to the same Logger and will be displayed collaboratively.

Now you will be able to see logs in your GCP's project Log tab :)

P.S. This will file log as info. You can use error or other classification options available to classify your log message type. For that, replace info with any following options to classify:

[image: Log classifications]

Any log level will display all types of logs.

Comment: Suppose, I have 30 Controllers then do I need to write this line `private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(ExampleController.class);` in all the Controllers?

Comment: Yes, you will need to . Just the classname would change. E.g. `ExampleController.class` will get replaced by `<ControllerClassName>.class`

Comment: I have used Apache Commons Logging but how to see the logs in Compute Engine google cloud platform. Please reply

Comment: in the gcp console, when you log in to project, you can find logger in the menu as this: https://imgur.com/a/z0oCn5c